# Why do I not have ODBC Driver 17 in my pyodbc drivers? How can I fix this in anaconda?

Tags: python, sql-server, anaconda, odbc, pyodbc

I keep getting this error when trying to connect to SQL server through pyodbc:

```
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

This is the string I am passing through pyodbc.connect():

```
'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
```

When I run print(pyodbc.drivers()), this is what is returned:

```
['SQL Server', 'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)', 'Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)', 'Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)']
```

How can I get the ODBC driver 17 to appear in my list of pyodbc drivers? For reference, I am running anaconda on windows on my work machine.

Many thanks

Comment: Launch `\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe` and check the "Drivers" tab. Do you see it there?

Comment: @GordThompson nope -- its not there. All the same drivers that are returned when I do pyodbc.drivers() are there.

Comment: Okay, so you don't have the 64-bit version of ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server installed. Last I checked, the process was a bit confusing in that the 32-bit installer installed *just* the 32-bit driver while the 64-bit installer installed both the 64-bit and 32-bit versions, but things may have changed. Anyway, head over to the [download page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) and try downloading the "x64" version again.

Comment: @GordThompson great -- that worked. thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The list returned by `pyodbc.drivers()` …

```
['SQL Server',
 'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)',
 'Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)',
 'Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)'
]
```

… indicates that the process is running under 64-bit Python on Windows because it doesn't include the legacy 32-bit Jet drivers like `Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)` that are automatically installed by the Windows setup program. Therefore we can conclude that the 64-bit version of `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server` simply wasn't installed on that machine. Installing it via

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server

resolved the issue.